# Skip first row when loading csv file into Apache Spark data frame in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks

In my [Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/what-is-azure-databricks#:%7E:text=Azure%20Databricks%20is%20a%20data,Microsoft%20Azure%20cloud%20services%20platform.&text=For%20a%20big%20data%20pipeline,Event%20Hub%2C%20or%20IoT%20Hub.) notebook, following code correctly loads the following data to an [Azure Apache Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/getting-started/spark/) `DataFrame`.

**Question**: How can I skip the first row from the `DataFrame` - either during the data load process or after the data has been loaded to the data frame?

**Goal**: File has millions of rows that need to be loaded to a SQL database except for the first row. File is too big to be opened in notepad or Excel. The process, eventually, needs to be automated.

**.CSV file**:

```
HD|20211210
DT|D-|12/22/2017|12/22/2017 09:41:45.828000|11/01/2017|01/29/2018 14:46:10.666000|1.2|1.2|ABC|ABC|123|123|4554|023|11/01/2017|ACDF|First|0012345||f|ABCD|ABCDEFGH|ABCDEFGH||||
DT|D-|12/25/2017|12/25/2017 09:24:20.202000|12/13/2017|01/29/2018 07:52:23.607000|6.4|6.4|ABC|ABC|123|123|4540|002|12/13/2017|ACDF|First|0012345||f|ABC|ABCDEF|ABCDEFGH||||
```

**[Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data#python)**:

```
sparkDF = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/MyDataFile.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")
display(sparkDF)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to repro this issue. I took below Sample CSV file with first row which is completely without schema.

[image]

I created schema for dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

customSchema = StructType([
                                    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True), 
                                    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                                    StructField("brandname", StringType(), True),
                                    StructField("num1", IntegerType(), True), 
                                    StructField("num2", FloatType(), True),
                                    StructField("num3", FloatType(), True),
                                    StructField("num4", FloatType(), True),
                                    StructField("name1", StringType(), True), 
                                    StructField("name2", StringType(), True),
                                    StructField("num5", FloatType(), True)])
```

[image]

Now I read csv file into dataframe.

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter",",").schema(customSchema).load("/FileStore/tables/PipeSeparated-1.csv")

df.display()
```

[image]

First row got eliminated because of schema mismatch.